# Macbook Pro 13 Early 2015 Display flickering and show rows

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I have recently bougth a broken Macbook pro 13' Early 2015. The display is the main issue. Infact, when the macbook turns on, the display shows this:
[image]

When it goes to login, the display shows this:
[image]

The image on the screen is flickering and also there are horizontal rows on the screen.

So I tried to connect the macbook to external display via HDMI cable and there are no issues.
I have tried to disassemble the macbook, but there are not particular issues inside.
I think the issue is not related to graphic card, but to display instead.

I have let to rest the macbook for few days, and today I turned on and the problems disappers. No rows,no flickering on the screen. Anyway after 5 minute the issue reappears.

I have no idea how I can fix it.

Have I to change the display? Assembly or only LCD? Or have I to check display cable?

Thank you

Comment: You are on the right track. I would bet it is a display issue and as you can see the Apple logo on the back of the lid through the display indicates it may be both the backlight and the display panel.

Comment: @SteveChambers thank you for the answer. How can I check the backlight and the display panel? The display panel seems no damaged, i.e. no cracked screen or any other external damage.

Comment: I exhausted my laptop display expertise there. You may need to seek out a forum that specializes in Mac hardware (ifixit.com, might help) if no one else here has other ideas.